# c#, what's the name of the concept that make an instance of object within the class definition itself?

Tags: c#, class, singleton

I've come across the singleton design pattern and noticed this, is singleton structure the only place you would make make an object within the class definition itself?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do it whenever you want, as for the name of the concept I don't think there is any. One examples where you use of private constructor, you can make class similar to enum with multiple values and having static readonly fields which are instances of the same class.
On a side note I wouldn't stress so much about this and go for what is needed, even though singleton is design pattern, it is also anti-pattern to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

"Singleton" is a relative term.

Once you accept that, it becomes acceptable to see an IoC container as a place to [construct a single object](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance). 
It doesn't attempt to make it hard to construct multiple instances but it makes it easy to use a single instance per "the plan" as well as other instances as needed, such as in tests.